# Automatically change column width in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a stackpanel with checkbox and combobox:

```
<StackPanel Name="PointSizeFilter"
            Style="{StaticResource StackPanelCell}">
    <CheckBox ... />
    <ComboBox ... />
</StackPanel>
```

And there is a datagrid. When the stackpanel's width is changed, I want datagrid column to be resized as well.

```
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGridEditable}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=IModel, Path=ControlPoints.Collection}"
          Name="DataGridCheckpoints">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{x:Static constants:Labels.ControlPointsObjectSize}"
                                Width="{Binding ElementName=PointSizeFilter, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static controlpoints:CpViewModel.PointSizeItems}}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PointSizeId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>                                    
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the Width property on DataGridColumn is not a double as ActualWidth, but a DataGridLength type. Try putting a converter in between.